# Access IIf statement in query

Tags: ms-access, iif

I think this should be straight forward. I have an insert query.
I am modifying a query field that is calling a public function that does a dlookup and it calculates any discounts.
I only want to call this function if an id is below a certain number. If above that number I want to populate it with a field from my form.
This is the original call:

```
GetTuition(Forms![createinvoice]!AfterschoolFrame,Forms!
[createinvoice]!BillCycleID,Forms![createinvoice]![1DayAfterschool15],Forms!
[createinvoice]![TuitionToPay]) AS Fee
```

But when I add an IIF, it crashes

```
IIf (Forms![createinvoice]!ScholarID <4
(GetTuition(Forms![createinvoice]!AfterschoolFrame,Forms!
[createinvoice]!BillingCycleID,
Forms![createinvoice]![1DayAfterschool15],
Forms![createinvoice]![TuitionToPay]) , Forms![createinvoice]!TuitionCost )) 
AS Fee
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You've made an error with your parentheses (you should remove the last one, and the 2nd one), and are missing a `,` after the if condition.

This fixes it:

```
IIf (Forms![createinvoice]!ScholarID <4, 
GetTuition(Forms![createinvoice]!AfterschoolFrame,Forms!
[createinvoice]!BillingCycleID,
Forms![createinvoice]![1DayAfterschool15],
Forms![createinvoice]![TuitionToPay]) , Forms![createinvoice]!TuitionCost) 
AS Fee
```

Comment: I made your changes (lost the , in my cut/paste) and it still doesn't work.   I have checked both my conditions, they work fine when done separately.  But when I put them in the IIF statement I get a 'data mismatch' error.

Comment: I have even reversed them (changing to >4- put that simple value in otherwise do the dlookup.  But same thing-

Comment: What's the data type on ScholarID?